# count the row that contains the same value of a specific field

Tags: shell, awk

Please, I have a file that contains fields separated by the character "|" I want to count the row that contains the same value in the field 1 and field 5

```
    abc|2|  11|   3| 1000|   0|scql|  29|   |   |   0|   0| plk| stv| 2| 0

    trc|2|  20|   3| 1200|   0|tkgl|   0| pajd|jahd| 0| 0| klm|fdkl|1|0
    mlm|2|  0|   3| 1300|   0|mlpo|  0|   |   |   0|   0| qnhd| pkjs| 2| 0

    klm|2|  0|   3| 1300|   0|mlpo|  0|   |   |   0|   0| qnhd| pkjs| 2| 0

    kkkm|2|  0|   3| 1600|   0|mlpo|  22|   |   |   0|   0| qnhd| pkjs| 2| 0

    ljkkk|9|  0|  5| 1600|   0|mlpo|  22|   |   |   0|   0| qnhd| pkjs| 2| 0

    klm|7|  0|   3| 1300|   0|mjkjlpo|  0|   |   |   6|   0| qnhd| pkjs| 2| 0

    kkkm|2|  0|   7| 1600|   0|mlpo|  22|   |   |   0|   0| qnhd| pkjs| 2| 0
```

the output should be like this:

```
abc        1000       1

trc        1200       1

mlm        1300       1

klm        1300       2

kkkm       1600       2

ljkkk      1600       1
```

I tried `awk -F\| 'NF > 1 {A[$5]++};END{for (field in A){print field"="A[field]}}'` but is based on one field which is 5. but it must be based on both 1 and 5

Thank you

Comment: i tried awk -F\| 'NF > 1 {A[$5]++};END{for (field in A){print field"="A[field]}}' but is for one field which is 5. but it must be based on both 1 and 5

Comment: post it in your question

Comment: ok it's done I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk -F' *\\| *' '{k=$1 OFS $5; b[k]++} END {for (i in b) print i, b[i]}' OFS='\t' file
klm     1300    2
trc     1200    1
abc     1000    1
mlm     1300    1
kkkm    1600    2
ljkkk   1600    1
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you, anubhava, my life is easier now. Great to see how stuff is done in awk without multidimensional arrays (since gawk 4).